# Printing whole row from excel with pandas or something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i need some help i try to do this abouth 2hours i was looking on internet but i couldnt find any solution,
i want from excel to print horizontal row from name that i found
here is picture what i want to print https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgmXi.jpg

```
elif "name " in data:
    baza = pd.read_excel('Baza.xlsx')
    data = data.split(" ")
    name = data[1]
    botgovor("Hold a second.I will check data base for that name")
    for name in baza:
        botgovor("We have that name in database,What would you like to do with it?")
        data = covekgovor()
        robot(data)
        if "check it" in data:
            informacije = pd.read_excel('Baza.xlsx')
            botgovor(informacije)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlrd

loc = ("excel_file.xlsx") # excel file name
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
search_name = "Landon"

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    if search_name == sheet.cell_value(i, 0):
        print(sheet.row_values(i))
```